# Creat treeview array or sub array

Tags: php, arrays, treeview

These are the data as they are in mysql table

Table A (Tasks)

```
task_id | name  | description
-----------------------------
  1     | soccer|  fora
-----------------------------
  2     | sussam|  forb
-----------------------------
  3     | sosssi|  forc
-----------------------------
  4     | sillly|  ford
```

Tabble B Milestones

```
mile_id | name   | task_id
------------------
  1     | task1mi |   1 
------------------
  2     | task2mi |   1
-------------------
  3     | task3mi |   3
```

I am looking to making a treeview array, something like for each task as a parent milestone as a child array of task id.

What the print_r() function should return (desired output with php after mysql query)

```
   array(          
          name=>'soccer',
          description =>'fora'
          task_id=>array(
                  mile_id=>'1',
                  name=>'task1mi'                   
             )
          )
```

Any Suggestions

Comment: does this a pure arrays or mysql tables ?

Comment: From what mysql returns using php, im looking to build an array tree from mysql results

Comment: why you don't use JOINS or sub queries instead of returning an arrays and then converting them to another view !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following way but it is not good for performance. I don`t know exact requirement and fretwork are you using. So i am giving basic idea.

```
$sqlparent = "select * from tasks";// get your task details from database.
$parentData = $sqlparent;// result from sql function.
foreach($parentData as $key=>$value)
{
   $sql = "select * from Milestones where task_id='".$value['task_id']."'";// find the Milestones of the task
$milestonesResult = mysql_featch_array($sql); // run sql and get data from database it is giving you single record you need to create loop here. as i don`t know what are you using for PHP.
$value['milestoneslist'] = $milestonesResult; //task_id=>array( here you can not use task_id => array as it is already there. if you do it it will over-right the task_id
}
```

I hope you will get idea from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your solution as i thought

```
$sql = "select table_b.*,table_a.name as aname, table_a.description as description as aname from table_b left join table_a on table_b.task_id=table_a.task_id"
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//based on above query result you will get array on mysql_fatch_assoc

$result_array = array();
while($result = mysql_fatch_assoc($result)){
    $tmp_arr = array();
    $tmp_arr['mile_id'] =  $result['mile_id'];
    $tmp_arr['name'] =  $result['name'];

    $result_array[$result['task_id']]['name'] = $result['aname'];
    $result_array[$result['task_id']]['description'] = $result['description'];
    $result_array[$result['task_id']]['task_id'][] = $tmp_arr;
}


$result_array = array_values($result_array);
print_r($result_array);
```